# dynamic lib in linux default library path doesn't work

Tags: linux, dynamic-library

I have copied a executable file to another machine, i have copied its dependent library to "/lib" directory too, but when i run that file, it still cannot find that library. when i set

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
```

it works properly。

Is the directory **"/lib"** a default path to find library? why it doesn't work until I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?  and is it totally unnecessary to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "/lib" which should be the **DEFAULT** path??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to run `ldconfig` to update the library location cache.